# ob_start() does not see the variables of the past

Tags: php, variables, include, buffer

I have a problem. That is the code:

```
$config = [
    'db' => '...',
    'root' => '...',
    ...
]

ob_start();
foreach ($files as $file) {
    include $file;
}
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

I use output buffering and display the result at the end. The problem is the included files doesn't see $config.

How can I make my OUTPUT BUFFERING to see the content before it, without adding $config in buffer ?

Any ideas? (thanks)

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the buffer/output buffering.  What is in the included file? A function?  That's why...

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: config...

Comment: Included files use $config. But they don't see it.

Comment: No, what is the CODE in the file?

Comment: It is a dynamic one. It is a framework and the included files are backend and frontend. Get it?

Comment: No, because you didn't show code but I gave you the answer in my first comment.

Comment: Dude. I trully don't understand...

Comment: Let's say in the files I have echo $config['db']. The point is it'll be an error cause doesn't see the $config... Get it now?

Comment: I think @AbraCadaver is hinting at http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: You don't get it. I already know these things from link you gave me. And are correct. But doesn't work with these BUFFER. Cause it doesn't see what was written before it.

Comment: Someone help me! Please.

Comment: Please show the code which triggers `Notice: Undefined variable: config`. The question is at risk of being closed.

Comment: <?= $config['db'] ?>

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you are mistaken about the causality of your error.  You can verify by putting the `$config` into the buffer, that it is already there.

Because you did not share the contents of the included file, I cannot tell you where your variable disappears to, but I can assure you it is there during the processing of that file.  It is there after as well, this can be verified by `var_dump($config)` at any point, inside or after the buffer.

Comment: I fixed it. Now I can see inside ob_start() what is created before it. Thank you.